# Why do these expressions have different levels of ambiguity?

Tags: overloading, type-inference, ambiguous, idris, function-composition

I am writing this function:

```
||| Returns the ten largest values in the list.
top_ten : Ord a => List a -> List a
```

My first attempt was a [pointfree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) implementation using function composition:

```
top_ten = take 10 . reverse . sort
```

But this gave the following error:

```
Main.idr:3:9:When checking right hand side of top_ten with expected type
        List a -> List a

Can't disambiguate name: Prelude.List.take, Prelude.Stream.take
```

My second attempt was a straightforward pointed implementation:

```
top_ten xs = take 10 (reverse (sort xs))
```

That works, as do these:

```
top_ten xs = take 10 $ reverse $ sort xs
top_ten xs = take 10 (reverse $ sort xs)
top_ten xs = take 10 $ reverse . sort $ xs
top_ten xs = take 10 (reverse . sort $ xs)
```

However, these do not:

```
top_ten xs = take 10 . reverse $ sort xs
top_ten xs = take 10 . reverse . sort $ xs
top_ten xs = take 10 $ (reverse . sort) xs
top_ten xs = (take 10 . reverse) (sort xs)
top_ten xs = take 10 ((reverse . sort) xs)
```

What exactly is going on here? **What is causing these equivalent expressions to have different levels of ambiguity?**

Comment: Idris type inference is not yet as capable as in Haskell/Agda.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the imports you have in scope (or functions from the Prelude) Idris is not capable to choose the correct functions as András Kovács said in his comment.

You can however help idris:

```
top_ten: Ord a => List a -> List a
top_ten = with Prelude.List take 10 . reverse . sort
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't entirely the answer of "why", but I was not aware of the `with` syntax. Could you post a link to the documentation for this syntax? All I've been able to find is a mention of it on the [homepage](https://www.idris-lang.org/) and [this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/idris-lang/qdiMrEpabpk/DbnwAKvKe94J).

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation either. It is just something I came across, probably by reading the mailing list.

Comment: Is it because the definition of `.` is typed to allow dependent application? If you define your own version of composition that doesn't allow for dependently typed functions (i.e. just `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`), does the overload resolution succeed?

Comment: @Cactus I'm not sure what you mean; that is the exact type signature of [`.` as it is defined in Idris](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/v1.0/libs/prelude/Prelude/Basics.idr#L34-L36).

Comment: @SamEstep: Sorry, you are exactly right. For some reason I assumed its type was something like `({x : a} -> (y : b x) -> c y) -> (g : (x : a) -> b x) -> ((x : a) -> c (g x))`.